# Crear un método try catch con la clase Scanner

Tags: java

deseo aclarar una duda.
Hay alguna forma de realizar un método para corregir errores de entrada en consola?

Me refiero a esto:
Tengo varios datos enteros que me pedirá la consola por medio del objeto Scanner.

```
int numero1 = sc.nextInt();
int numero2 = sc.nextInt();
int numero3 = sc.nextInt();
```

Si coloco por error un caracter o cadena que no sea un numero, me saldrá un mensaje de error y pedirá escribir de nuevo la entrada correcta. No quiero hacer un bloque try catch para cada variable, sino un método que funcione de igual manera. ¿Es posible?

Comment: El uso del `try/catch` es para manejar errores "excepcionales" que no pueden anticiparse en la ejecución del programa. En este caso lo práctico es leer la entrada del usuario como una cadena, validar que esa cadena represente un entero y luego hacer la conversión a tipo entero.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el comentario anterior. Try/catch se usa solo para manejar errores que no se puedan anticipar a la hora de ejecutar.

Pero para solucionar tu problema podrías optar por algo así:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int a;
    try{
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor");
        a=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Por favor, ingrese un dato valido");
    }
```

Esto no es lo más óptimo, pero podría solucionarte por ahora! Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Logré buscar una forma de hacer un método para mi problema. No sé si es lo ideal, pero me está funcionando.

```
/**
 * validarNumero verifica que el numero ingresado se encuentre dentro de los limites establecidos,
 *  ademas de validar que se este ingresando un numero entero
 * @param minimo primer extremo del limite de numeros enteros
 * @param maximo segundo extremo del limite de numeros enteros
 * @return numero, un entero
 */
private static int validarNumero(int minimo, int maximo) {
    /**
     * Si la variable "minimo" fuera mayor a la variable "maximo", intercambia extremos
     */
    if (minimo > maximo) {
        int aux = minimo;
        minimo = maximo;
        maximo = aux;
    }

    int numero = 0;
    do {

        try {
            numero = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

            if (!(numero >= minimo && numero <= maximo)) {
                System.out.println("Debes escribir un número entre el rango de " + minimo +" a "+ maximo);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Solo numeros:");
            //Si el dato ingresado no fuera numero, se vuleve a llamar al metodo n veces hasta que se obtenga un dato valido
            numero = validarNumero(minimo, maximo);
        }

    } while (!(numero >= minimo && numero <= maximo));
    return numero;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, hay mejores formas de hacerlo. Ahorita publico una respuesta que te podría servir

Comment: Ahorita ya analizando más tu código no te recomendaría para nada usar ese código puesto que funciona de manera recursiva que en ciertos casos podría llegar a llenar la memoria Stack de las llamadas a tu función causando el famoso "StackOverflow"; también haces dos veces la comparación de rango (mínimo y máximo), lo cual para nada es necesario.

Answer (score 0):

[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) tiene consigo métodos que ya detectan si la siguiente entrada tiene el formato que se busca. En este caso como es lectura de enteros usamos [`scanner.hasNextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt())

Internamente `scanner.hasNextInt`valida con [REGEX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) y con `try catch`

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    // Tiene el modificador private puesto que en este ejemplo sólo se usará en esta clase
    // Tanto scanner como el método son estáticos para que puedan ser accesados dentro del Main (otro contexto estático)
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number1 = readNumber(0, 120, "Please enter a valid number: ");
        int number2 = readNumber(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 2, "Please enter other valid number in binary form: ");

        // Impresión con formato
        System.out.printf("%s %d, %d", "You entered the next numbers: ", number1, number2);
    }

     /**
     * This method will read a integer decimal number
     * @param min min integer value accepted
     * @param max max integer value accepted
     * @param msg the message that will be displayed for asking the entrance
     * @return a integer number between max and min read from STDIN
     */
    public static int readNumber(int min, int max, String msg) {
        return readNumber(min, max, 10, msg);
    }

    /**
     * @param min min integer value accepted
     * @param max max integer value accepted
     * @param radix radix of the input
     * @param msg the message that will be displayed for asking the entrance
     * @return a integer number between max and min read from STDIN
     */
    private static int readNumber(int min, int max, int radix, String msg) {
        int number;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(msg);
            // Si lo siguiente en el búfer no es entero entonces:
            if (!scanner.hasNextInt(radix)) {
                System.err.println("Invalid entrance\nThe entrance must be a integer number");
                // Limpiando la entrada inválida
                scanner.nextLine();
                continue;
            }
            // Se lee el entero y se limpia el búfer sobrante por si acaso
            number = scanner.nextInt(radix);
            scanner.nextLine();
            // Validación máximo y mínimo
            if ( number < min || number > max ) {
                System.err.printf(
                        "%s %d %s %d, %s",
                        "Invalid number\nThe number must be between", min,
                        " and ",
                        max,
                        " (inclusive).\n"
                );
                continue;
            }
            return number;
        }

    }

}
```

Así se ve el método de `hasNextInt` de acuerdo al OPENJDK 15 e IntelliJ

```java
    public boolean hasNextInt(int radix) {
        setRadix(radix);
        boolean result = hasNext(integerPattern());
        if (result) { // Cache it
            try {
                String s = (matcher.group(SIMPLE_GROUP_INDEX) == null) ?
                    processIntegerToken(hasNextResult) :
                    hasNextResult;
                typeCache = Integer.parseInt(s, radix);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```