# Como hacer que cuando no se introduzca un numero de error y vuelva a repetir

Tags: java

> Realiza un programa que pida números al usuario, en caso de que el usuario introduzca un carácter
> que no sea un número debe mostrar un mensaje de error y volver a pedir el número nuevamente.
> El programa finalizará cuando se introduzca un número negativo.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PRINCIPAL2_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        int numero =0;
        int numero2=0;
        
        do{
        
            System.out.println("INTRODUCE UN NUMERO");
            numero=teclado.nextInt();
            
            {do {
                System.out.println("EL CARACTER INTRODUCIDO NO ES UN NUMERO, VUELVA A INTRODUCIR UN NUMERO");
                numero2=teclado.nextInt();
                
            }while(numero );}
        }
        while(numero>0);
        
        }
    }
```

En el ejercicio me pide que le pida al usuario número y cuando se escriba un número negativo se acabe, eso está hecho, lo que no tengo claro de como hacerlo es que mientras escribes los numero si pones un caracter que no es un número de error y vuelva a mandar escribirlo.

Comment: Tal vez te ayude [una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/448368/crear-un-m%c3%a9todo-try-catch-con-la-clase-scanner/448395#448395) que publiqué hace tiempo

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacer uso de un `Try catch` ,ya que al momento de ingresar un caracter el copilador nos genera una Excepción.ojo que si se debe detener con numeros negativos no te olvides del 0 ;)

```
 boolean pass=true;   

          do{
              System.out.println("INTRODUCE UN NUMERO");
            try{
            numero=teclado.nextInt();
            pass=false;
           }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("EL CARACTER INTRODUCIDO NO ES UN NUMERO, VUELVA A INTRODUCIR UN NUMERO");
            teclado.next();//borramos la entrada incorrecta
           }
          
         }while(pass||numero>=0);//
```